# JQuery multiple variables sent in url

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have searched for hours now to find out how I could do this, but unfortunately all to no avail.

I am trying to send entered information so it can run through MySQL and obtain the information, then echo it in table on screen.

The issue (as far as I can tell) must be with my JQuery code:

```
    $("#btnCheckNoteIDs").click(function(){
    var noteUser = $("#noteUser").val();
    var noteDate = $("#noteDate").val();
  $("#LoadNoteIDs").load('check_noteIDs.php?noteDate='+noteDate + "&noteUser="+noteUser);
});
```

My php code is as follows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT ID, ClientID, Note, ToDoDate, CaseID
FROM ToDoNotes
WHERE ToDoStatus='0' and Deleted='0' and `ToDoDate`='".$_GET['noteIDsDate']."' and User='".$_GET['noteIDsDate']."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$ID = $row['ID'];
$ClientID = $row['ClientID'];
$Note = $row['Note'];
$ToDoDate = $row['ToDoDate'];
$CaseID = $row['CaseID'];
}

?>

<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Note ID</th>
<th>Client ID</th>
<th>Case ID</th>
<th>Note</th>
<th>To Do Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><? echo $noteID; ?></td>
<td><? echo $ClientID; ?></td>
<td><? echo $CaseID; ?></td>
<td><? echo $Note; ?></td>
<td><? echo $ToDoDate; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone here offer any assistance please? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: post your php code in check_noteIDs.php as well.

Comment: When you click on the button, are you able to see the request being sent in your browser network tab?

Comment: @ArminSam No, all it does it loads the check_noteIDs.php page with the table headers and no information?

EDIT: It has this in the network tab:

`check_noteIDs.php?noteDate=undefined&noteUser=undefined`

Comment: Looks like you do not have any param data at all. The problem seems to be in your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have form.php like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="btnCheckNoteIDs">
        <label> User</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="noteUser"><br>
        <label>Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="noteDate"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="LoadNoteIDs"></div>    
</body>
</html>

<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

        $(document ).ready(function() { //make sure document is ready     
          $('#btnCheckNoteIDs').submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();//to prevent default behaviour

          var noteUser = $("#noteUser").val();
          var noteDate = $("#noteDate").val();
          if(noteUser==undefined){
            alert('No noteuser');
            return false;
          }else if(noteDate==undefined){
            alert('no note date');
             return false;//stop sending
          }
        //to convert %2F, use decodeURIComponent
          var param= 'noteDate='+decodeURIComponent(noteDate) + '&noteUser='+noteUser;
            $.ajax({
              url: "check_noteIDs.php",
              data: param,
              type: "post",
              success: function(data){
                    $('#LoadNoteIDs').html(data);
              }
            });
           });
         });

</script>
```

in check_noteIDs.php which must be in the same folder where you put the form.php

```
require_once "dbconfig.php";

 $user= isset($_REQUEST['noteUser'])? $_REQUEST['noteUser']:'';
 $date = isset($_REQUEST['noteDate'])? date('Y-m-d', strototime($_REQUEST['noteDate'])):'';
 //You can validate here.

 $result = mysqli_query($con," SELECT ID, ClientID, Note, 
                                ToDoDate, CaseID
                                FROM `ToDoNotes`
                                WHERE `ToDoStatus`='0' AND `Deleted`='0' 
                                AND `ToDoDate`='$date' 
                                AND `User`='$user'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Note ID</th>
       <th>Client ID</th>
       <th>Case ID</th>
       <th>Note</th>
       <th>To Do Date</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['ClientID']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['CaseID']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['Note']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ToDoDate']; ?></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
<?php
mysqli_free_result($result);    
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This appears to be adding it to the url, which is 1 step forward... The issue now seems to be that instead of loading the table with the information in on the page that I clicked the submit button, it is taking me to a completely separate page

Comment: That means you have to prevent default submit.

Comment: Ah ha, I think this may be getting there now!

Last issue which I think could be causing the problem... noteDate is a date that is selected (obviously) but in the URL it appears like this:

`01%2F11%2F2016` if I pick today's date. Any quick fixes for this please? @Mawia HL

Comment: I think I may have resolved the date issue by calling the GET before putting it into the SELECT query like so:

`$noteDate = $_GET['noteDate'];$noteDate = str_replace("/", "-", $noteDate);$noteDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($noteDate));`

Only issue now appears to be that my table isn't loading on the page any more... Problem after problem! @Mawia HL

Comment: Instead of $_GET, use $_REQUEST or $_POST if you are using the code here.

Comment: I have managed to get the table showing... It works as long as there is no date selected (and I change the SELECT query to not include the date). As soon as a date is selected (with it added into the SELECT query also) then it fails

Comment: put this print_r($_REQUEST['noteDate']; at the top of the php page and see the result.

Comment: This causes a 500 error and will not run/load. I can see from the URL when I choose a date that it is as stated above (`01%2F11%2F2016`).

I thought it was working with just noteUser but apparently it isn't. It's just showing 1 result, which is even shown if I run the form empty. I'm so lost...

Comment: Post the complete code. Or Check your network tab and see the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the submit button in your form, submits the form before the script executes. If that's the case, you need to update your script as below:

```js
$("#btnCheckNoteIDs").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var noteUser = $("#noteUser").val();
    var noteDate = $("#noteDate").val();
    $("#LoadNoteIDs").load('check_noteIDs.php?noteDate='+noteDate + "&noteUser="+noteUser);
});
```